# Code for Linked List Insertion not giving any output

Tags: c++, debugging, linked-list

I've been working on this problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/

```
You are given the pointer to the head node of a linked list and an integer to add to the list. Create a new node with the given integer. Insert this node at the tail of the linked list and return the head node of the linked list formed after inserting this new node. The given head pointer may be null, meaning that the initial list is empty.

Function Description

Complete the insertNodeAtTail function in the editor below.

insertNodeAtTail has the following parameters:

SinglyLinkedListNode pointer head: a reference to the head of a list
int data: the data value for the node to insert
Returns

SinglyLinkedListNode pointer: reference to the head of the modified linked list
Input Format

The first line contains an integer , the number of elements in the linked list.
The next  lines contain an integer each, the value that needs to be inserted at tail.

Constraints

Sample Input

STDIN Function ----- -------- 5 size of linked list n = 5 141 linked list data values 141..474 302 164 530 474

Sample Output

141
302
164
530
474
Explanation

First the linked list is NULL. After inserting 141, the list is 141 -> NULL.
After inserting 302, the list is 141 -> 302 -> NULL.
After inserting 164, the list is 141 -> 302 -> 164 -> NULL.
After inserting 530, the list is 141 -> 302 -> 164 -> 530 -> NULL. After inserting 474, the list is 141 -> 302 -> 164 -> 530 -> 474 -> NULL, which is the final list.
```

I wrote the following code:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
SinglyLinkedListNode* temp=head;
if (temp!=NULL){
while (temp->next!=NULL){
    temp=temp->next;
}
SinglyLinkedListNode newNode(data);
temp->next=&newNode;
}
return head;
}
```

However, I am not getting any output on stdout. Can someon tell what's the issue with my code?

//For the user  some programmer dude only, rest may ignore:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
SinglyLinkedListNode* temp=head;
if (temp!=NULL){
while (temp->next!=NULL){
    temp=temp->next;
}
auto newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
temp->next = newNode;
}
return head;
}
```

Even this code is not working.

Comment: first of all, you are not printing any output and second, the link doesn't open, maybe it's restricted. share publicly viewable link.

Comment: Let me share the link

Comment: Or better, don't share any links and make your question self-contained by adding all required information to it. Also your code has undefined behaviour  because you are adding the address of a local variable.

Comment: I tried printing the value as well by using cout, but it was still not working @user13145713

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list/

Comment: As usual: make a [mcve]. You won't do it, I know. But it's worth trying...

Comment: @proglove you are not creating any node when the list is empty.

Comment: and just returning the null head pointer back to the main function.

Comment: And don't ask to not downvote. That alone is worth a downvote! Anyway what happens when head is NULL?

Comment: Ops, @user13145713 beat me on spotting the error.

Comment: It will return a null pointer @CostantinoGrana

Comment: @proglove no, it should create a new node with the given data/value.

Comment: @user13145713 Can you please tell by commenting below what should be the addition to my code to make it work correctly?

Comment: When you say "not working", what do you mean by that? ***How*** is it "not working"? Have you tried using a debugger to see if there's a crash? Or just to step through the code statement by statement?

Comment: It still is not giving any output and fails all testcases @Someprogrammerdude, no offence intended

Comment: I have tried to go through the code line by line @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @user13145713 I would be really grateful if you could comment below your code and help a new learner .

Comment: By the way, what happens if you call this to add the first node to the list? Will you ever call this function with a null `head` pointer? What about an *uninitialized* (and *indeterminate*) `head` pointer? We really need to see a [mcve] to be able to help you properly!

Comment: Should I copy-paste the Hackerrank details of the question? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I included the HackerRank link over here, so that all of us can have a look at the problem and try it live on the code editor. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @proglove here :     SinglyLinkedListNode* temp=head;
    if (temp!=NULL){
        while (temp->next!=NULL){
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        auto newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
    else{
        auto newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
        head = newNode;      
    }
    return head;

Comment: as suggested by @Someprogrammerdude create a node like that, you just didn't handle the case when the head is `NULL`. The above code works.

Answer (score 2):

These two lines are the likely problem:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode newNode(data);
temp->next=&newNode;
```

The variable `newNode` is a *local* variable, inside the scope of the `if`. Once the body of the `if` ends, so does the life-time of the `newNode` variable, and the object will be destructed. That leaves any pointer to the object invalid.

You must create the object dynamically:

```
auto newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode(data);
temp->next = newNode;
```

---

With that said, I recommend that you stop using plain non-owning pointers, and instead take look at [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Please see the edited question once.

Comment: @proglove Please don't change your question if you get an answer. SO is no interactive forum, where we walk you through all the changes until your code works. It's a Q&A-site, if you still encoutner problems, please ask a new question.

Comment: @churill I still haven't got the answer, I just edited the question to include all the details in the question itself.

Comment: @churill If you know the solution, please help :)

Comment: @proglove We need a full [mre]. Yet, your original code was wrong, this answer corrects it, so after changing this, the answer became invalue and we don't even have a clue what could be wrong.